# How to choose a random enumeration value

Tags: random, swift, enums

I am trying to randomly choose an enum value:

```
enum GeometryClassification {

    case Circle
    case Square
    case Triangle
    case GeometryClassificationMax

}
```

and the random selection:

```
let shapeGeometry = ( arc4random() % GeometryClassification.GeometryClassificationMax ) as GeometryClassification
```

but it fails.

I get errors like:

```
'GeometryClassification' is not convertible to 'UInt32'
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Swift has gained new features since this answer was written that provide a much better solution — see "[How to choose a random enumeration value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261011/how-to-choose-a-random-enumeration-value/53603643#53603643)" instead.

---

I'm not crazy about your last case there -- it seems like you're including `.GeometryClassificationMax` solely to enable random selection. You'll need to account for that extra case everywhere you use a `switch` statement, and it has no semantic value. Instead, a static method on the `enum` could determine the maximum value and return a random case, and would be much more understandable and maintainable.

```
enum GeometryClassification: UInt32 {
    case Circle
    case Square
    case Triangle

    private static let _count: GeometryClassification.RawValue = {
        // find the maximum enum value
        var maxValue: UInt32 = 0
        while let _ = GeometryClassification(rawValue: maxValue) { 
            maxValue += 1
        }
        return maxValue
    }()

    static func randomGeometry() -> GeometryClassification {
        // pick and return a new value
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(_count)
        return GeometryClassification(rawValue: rand)!
    }
}
```

And you can now exhaust the `enum` in a `switch` statement:

```
switch GeometryClassification.randomGeometry() {
case .Circle:
    println("Circle")
case .Square:
    println("Square")
case .Triangle:
    println("Triangle")
}
```

Comment: you are right - i went with this approach in the end to make it more readable. thank you for the effort.

Comment: `++maxValue` will be deprecated in Swift 3. How would you go about fixing that in your code?

Comment: @Cesare: You can move the increment inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on how you can you make this code reusable? I have three enums in my app and I'm using this code three times. I thought about creating a class (because you can't extend an enum with an extension?).

Answer (score 103):

In Swift there is actually a protocol for enums called `CaseIterable` that, if you add it to your enum, you can just reference all of the cases as a collection with `.allCases` as so:

```
enum GeometryClassification: CaseIterable {

    case Circle
    case Square
    case Triangle

}
```

and then you can `.allCases` and then `.randomElement()` to get a random one

```
let randomGeometry = GeometryClassification.allCases.randomElement()!
```

The force unwrapping is required because there is a possibility of an enum having no cases and thus `randomElement()` would return `nil`.

Comment: The lowercase and lack of parenthesis on the .allCases is important.  I accidentally used `GeometryClassification.AllCases().randomElement()!` (thank you autocompletion) which is completely different and resulted in a runtime error.

Comment: For Swift 5 here is a something from Apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomnumbergenerator

Comment: Thanks! This should be the accepted answer in 2022.

Answer (score 9):

For Swift 5 there is "[RandomNumberGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomnumbergenerator)":

```
enum Weekday: CaseIterable {
    case sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday

    static func random<G: RandomNumberGenerator>(using generator: inout G) -> Weekday {
        return Weekday.allCases.randomElement(using: &generator)!
    }

    static func random() -> Weekday {
        var g = SystemRandomNumberGenerator()
        return Weekday.random(using: &g)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since you're inside the enum class, having the `random()` method reference the highest value explicitly would eliminate having to count them every time:

```
enum GeometryClassification: UInt32 {
    case Circle
    case Square
    case Triangle

    static func random() -> GeometryClassification {
        // Update as new enumerations are added
        let maxValue = Triangle.rawValue

        let rand = arc4random_uniform(maxValue+1)
        return GeometryClassification(rawValue: rand)!
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as of Swift 1.2. It wants a rawValue assigned to the enum. In turn it means that it only works with enums with an Int rawValue type.

Comment: I had a typo on my code, was returning the wrong type.

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign a raw type to your enum. If you use an integer type, then the enumeration case values will be auto-generated starting at 0:

```
enum GeometryClassification: UInt32 {  
    case Circle
    case Square
    case Triangle
    case GeometryClassificationMax
}
```

Per [Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Enumerations.html):

> "Unlike C and Objective-C, Swift enumeration members are not assigned a default integer value when they are created."

Specifying the integer type lets it know to generate the values in the usual way.

Then you can generate the random value like this:

```
let randomEnum: GeometryClassification = GeometryClassification.fromRaw(arc4random_uniform(GeometryClassification.GeometryClassificationMax.toRaw()))!
```

This is a horribly ugly call, and all those `fromRaw` and `toRaw` calls are fairly inelegant, so I would really recommend generating a random UInt32 that is in the range you want first, then creating a `GeometryClassification` from that value:

```
GeometryClassification.fromRaw(someRandomUInt32)
```

Comment: You don't need to assign the specific values in this case; they'll be auto-generated starting at `0`. The part you quoted from the docs is only if the `enum` doesn't have in integer-based raw type. Further down in the same doc: "When integers are used for raw values, they auto-increment if no value is specified for some of the enumeration members."

Comment: @SebastianFlückiger you'll need to create the `GeometryClassification` from the raw value returned from `arc4random`:  `let shapeGeometry = GeometryClassification(rawValue: ( arc4random() % GeometryClassification.GeometryClassificationMax.rawValue ))`

Comment: @MikeS I am not sure that a UInt32 is the same as 'an integer' in that context. I would assume it is, but I would argue that if the enum is going to be used this way, the more specificity the better. Still, I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @0O0O0O0 It will auto-generate values with `UInt32` just fine. The values should also start with `0` if they're going to work correctly with the value returned from `arc4random` (as it's currently used anyway).

Comment: @SebastianFlückiger See my edits above - that should be all you need to get it working. Let me know if you still have trouble.

Comment: thanks! managed it myself in the end and landed on the exact same solution :) happy now :P

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the values into array and generate random,

```
extension GeometryClassification {

    static func random() -> GeometryClassification {
        let all: [GeometryClassification] = [.Circle,
                                             .Square,
                                             .Triangle,
                                             .GeometryClassificationMax]
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random()) % all.count
        return all[randomIndex]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to create a global extension:

```
extension CaseIterable {
    static func randomElement() -> AllCases.Element {
        guard Self.allCases.count > 0 else {
            fatalError("There must be at least one case in the enum")
        }
        return Self.allCases.randomElement()!
    }
}
```

This way any enum which conforms to `CaseIterable` has the function automatically

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Swift 1.2 take:

```
enum GeometryClassification : Int {
    case Circle = 0
    case Square = 1
    case Triangle = 2

    static func random() -> GeometryClassification {
        let min = MutationType.Circle.rawValue
        let max = MutationType.Triangle.rawValue
        let rand = Int.random(min: min, max: max) // Uses ExSwift!
        return self(rawValue: rand)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a global extension using [Andy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357617/13261714) answer. Enjoy :)

```
extension CaseIterable {
    static func random<G: RandomNumberGenerator>(using generator: inout G) -> Self.AllCases.Element {
        return Self.allCases.randomElement(using: &generator)!
    }

    static func random() -> Self.AllCases.Element {
        var g = SystemRandomNumberGenerator()
        return Self.random(using: &g)
    }
}
```

Just extend your enumeration to conform CaseIterable protocol and use like:

```
let state = YourEnum.random()
```