# Return a random case from an enum in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I just wrote a function that generates a random integer in a range of 0...2. The goal is to return a random case from an enum based on the random integer.

I'd like to prefer to use the case statement but I don't like the default case which returns an arbitrary enum. Omitting the default case will not work since switch is not able to know how much cases will occur. Even though the default case would *never* happen I don't consider this to be a clean solution.

Which solution would you prefer respectively consider to be the cleanest solution - please elaborate. Is there a better/more elegant way to return a random case from an enum?

If-else solution:

```
    func generateRandomSign() -> Sign {
        let randomSelection = Int.random(in: 0...2)

        if randomSelection == 0 {
            return .rock
        } else if randomSelection == 1 {
            return .paper
        }
        return .scissor
    }
```

Switch solution:

```
    func generateRandomSign() -> Sign {
        let randomSelection = Int.random(in: 0...2)

        switch randomSelection {
        case 0: return .rock
        case 1: return .paper
        case 2: return .scissor
        default: return .rock
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a note on both options, for the first you can replace `} else if randomSelection == 2 {`with just `} else {` because that is the only option not covered yet and using the same logic you can remove `case 2:` in your switch and let `default` return `.scissor`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261011/how-to-choose-a-random-enumeration-value

Comment: Thank you @Joakim Danielson. Your hint about ommitting `case 2` and handling it via the default case shed some light into my issue.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I ommitted the second `if else` statement since it was cruft and posted accidentally.

Comment: hmmm why the downvote?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need for messing around with `Int`s. You should rather declare your `Sign` `enum` to conform to `CaseIterable` and call `randomElement()` on its `allCases` property (which as its name suggests, contains all cases of the `enum`).

This way you don't sacrifice type safety and you're guaranteed to get back a case of `Sign` every time.

```
enum Sign: CaseIterable {
    case rock
    case paper
    case scissor

    static func random() -> Sign {
        return allCases.randomElement()! // safe to force unwrap, since the enum has at least 1 property, so this can never be `nil`
    }
}
```

You can call it like `let randomSign = Sign.random()`

Comment: Thank you very much for the sophisticated (at least from my perspective as a beginner ^^) solution. But for now I'm going to stay with the approach to assign a random `Int` to a case since this is what the course demands. @Joakim Danielson cleared things up for me in regards to the switch statement.